# How to keep track of number of lines since marker?

Tags: luatex

I'm trying to keep track of the number of lines since some marker so that I can change the contents of the `\localleftbox` at specific lines.  To that end, I've been experimenting with the following simple document (where I simply try to show the line number in the `\localleftbox` even though in the final document I'm *not* showing line numbers, but have completely different contents for the box):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcount\test%
\test=0
\def\testincrement{\global\advance\test by 1\relax%
    \the\test\hspace{1em}}

\def\markeron{
    \test=0
    \localleftbox{%
        \unexpanded{\testincrement}%
    }
}
\def\markeroff{\localleftbox{}}

\begin{document}

\markeron
hello \the\test\\
hi \the\test\\
\advance\test by 1\relax% manually advance test to see if the box will change
goodbye \the\test\\
really \the\test
\markeroff

\blindtext

\markeron
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

However, the `\localleftbox` is always showing the same number.  This seems to be due to two problems:

1. `\global\advance\test by 1\relax` isn't functional inside the `\localleftbox` so the counter `\test` is stays at 1.
2. Even when `\test` is advanced outside the `\localleftbox` the contents of the box do not respond to this and continue to display 1.

Any suggestions for how to fix this or another way to do it?

Comment: `\localleftbox` always directly sets the content into a box, doing all expansion and execution immediately. So `\global\advance\test` works, but it is only executed once directly when `\localleftbox` is called.

Comment: If you know the content (or at least the width) of the localleftbox and you only want to change a fixed number of boxes, you can do some tricks with `\latelua` and `\parshape`, but for that we need some additional information what you are trying to archive.

Comment: remember that linebreaking in luatex, the same as classic tex works _after_ the entire paragraph has been typeset to a single horizontal line, so after all macros expanded and assignments ,made.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger In actual use case, the boxes are set as if the have 0 width so that their contents end up behind the text.  Said contents are a a set of lines and spaces designed to span the `\textwidth`.  What needs to change is the split between lines and spaces and once the change happens, it should persist until we make another change (which could be to just empty the box entirely).

Comment: does your real text just have forced line breaks as here? In which case you can use paragraph breaks rather than line breaks which makes everything a lot easier as you can update localleftbox between paragraphs but not between lines.

Comment: @rpspringuel Oh, then all the linebreaking issues immediately disappear. Do you expect markers to appear in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: The line breaking is generally automatic in the sections, but there is the possibility of a user specified break.  In the code I’m working with, the code for the manual break inserts a `\penalty{-10001}` (after doing a whole bunch of other stuff to make the end of the line look good in context).  Whether or not there are lines is a paragraph level decision, but the lines then change their visual width within the paragraph.  The general pattern is to have space-lines-space behind each line of text, with the spaces being bigger for the first x lines (where x is determined by the user).